# Select * from 2 tables where CatergoryID's are 1

Tags: mysql, database, join

I've got these tables:

```
table : _newapp_shop_products_events
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   EventID  |   categoryID    |   Price  |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   9050    |   1    |   15.00 |
|   5048  |   2    |    12.00  |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+

table : _newapp_shop_products_categories
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   CategoryID  |   Category_Name    |   photo    |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   1   |   Tickets    |    one.jpg   |
|   2   |   Voucher    |    two.jpg   |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+

table : _newapp_shop_products_activitys
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   ActivityID  |   categoryID    |   Price  |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   80    |   1    |   13.00 |
|   95  |   2    |    18.00  |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
```

And these are linked by a relationship,  categories -> events, categories -> activities.

I want to display events and activities (the Events and Activity Tables not the _newapp ones) in one list and only display the items from both tables with categoryID = 1 for example. How would I solve this?

I have tried to join them or select them both in a union, it returns the rows fine but the internal link within mysql is broken. when I click on the second result set from 'Activitys' the id is correct and the price but when i click the id to go to the corresponding id it gives 0 rows result as it generates the query: `SELECT * FROM representin_nl_-_1.Events WHERE Id = 5` But that is the wrong table, it should search it in `SELECT * FROM representin_nl_-_1._newapp_shop_products_activitys WHERE Id = 5` instead. Result: [image: result] The first 9050 when i click it, it goes to the correct row but the ids after that are `not found`. Result: [image]

[image]

Comment: And what have you tried so far???

Comment: I have tried to join them or select them both in a union, it returns the rows fine but the internal link within mysql is broken. when I click on the second result set from 'Activitys' the id is correct and the price but when i click the id to go to the corresponding id it gives 0 rows result as it generates the query: `SELECT * FROM representin_nl_-_1.Events WHERE Id = 5` But that is the wrong table, it should search it in `SELECT * FROM representin_nl_-_1._newapp_shop_products_activitys WHERE Id = 5` instead.

Comment: How can there be a link in a database?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want a UNION

```
SELECT 'Event' AS Type, EventID AS Id, Price
FROM Events
WHERE CategoryId = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Activity' AS Type, ActivityID AS Id, Price
FROM Activity
WHERE CategoryId = 1
```

What do you mean Id conflict? You could do something like this instead

```
SELECT EventID, null AS ActivityId, Price
FROM Events
WHERE CategoryId = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT null, ActivityID, Price
FROM Activity
WHERE CategoryId = 1
```

Comment: looks good. When I click on the EventID I get the row belonging to it, but when I click the ActivityID i get result 0 rows, how is this possible?

Comment: @codGmer - Click where? You haven't mentioned which software you are using to do the query...